# javascript fetch-api doesnt proceed with .then(), but backend responds with correct JSON-Object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, fetch-api

Node.js-Version: 18.13.0
Vue-cli-Version: 5.0.8

I am currently developing a webapp with JS and Vue in the Frontend and Spring Boot and a temporary H2-Database in the backend.
When I test my webapp I run my frontend and backend at the same time on different ports.
I am currently stuck on a simple fetch request to the backend which doesnt proceed to the following .then().

The Frontend Code:

```
const userData = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      }

      const emailRequestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
      }

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/register', userData)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

          console.log("test1")

          if (data.ok) {

            console.log("test2")
            
            fetch('http://localhost:8080/userEmail/' + this.email, emailRequestOptions)
              .then(response2 => response2.json())
              .then(data2 => this.navigateToRegistrationQuestions(data2))
              .catch(error => {
                console.error('error:', error)
              })

          } else {

            console.log('User could not be created, try again')
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('error:', error)
        })
```

The Backend Endpoints:

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request){

        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.register(request));
    }


    @GetMapping("/userEmail/{email}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Long>> getUserIdByEmail(@PathVariable String email) { 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(uService.getUserIdByEmail(email));
    }
```

My Backend returns this response when I test the request with Postman:
{ "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJo" }
which is what I expect, so that works fine.

I already tried to debug it a bit, with the console.log("test"), ("test2") but I dont get any of theses outputs and also no errors in my console browser.
Therefore I assume it is stuck on the .then(data => {....}), but I dont know why.
Is it maybe, because the response takes too long?

Comment: Try to place a console.log here `.then(response => response.json())` like this: `.then(response => {console.log("response: ", response); return response.json()})`

Comment: *JS-Version: 18.13.0* please explain.

Comment: What do you see in your devtools console and network tabs? I suspect you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and that no [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) are present on the response.

Comment: (Side note: You're missing an important check in your `fetch` code thanks to a footgun in the API. You need to test the `ok` property on the initial response to find out if the HTTP call worked [`fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors like 404 or 500]. More on my old anemic blog [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)

Comment: In my network tab there is only listed: 
chunk-vendor.js, app.js, the vue-view and something called ws.
So it has to do with my CORS Configuration in the backend? And thanks btw for the side note, it really makes sense :).
I think I also have to mention, that everytime I execute the request, the site refreshes.

Comment: JS v18, Vue 5? Maybe you means Node.js v18, vue-cli v5. They're different.

Comment: @KaiKai I thought so.

Comment: @KaiKai yeah thats what i meant

Comment: I FOUND THE SOLUTION! I feel a little stupid, it was actually because I forgot to include event.preventDefault() in the function. So the site always refreshed after the function was executed because it is a function that gets executed when using a button.